Having issues with solana cli token distribution, recieving error PickleDbError(Error { msg: EOF while parsing a value })
enter image description hereHi im recieving the error above in the title while running solana-tokens distribute-tokens on devnet. im following the instructions correctly. Below im adding an image of the error and other variables in the code. [enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/LhrL6Vcd.png)
I tirend looking on the internet but didnt find anything about this error.

can we have the .yml and the .csv file to test it out?

Hi there thank you for reaching out! I realized with your messege that the problem is probably the fact that my .yml file is empty since I didnt find what to put in there anywhere. If you could give me some pointers as to what to write there and so on I would really appreciate it. I added the .csv file above.
@MohamadjavadSafari

i posted the correct answer try it out and confirm it if its ok, thanks.

Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please do not link code/ console content as images and instead copy-paste it in the text of the question with proper formatting

In your code the --db-path must be the output path of the db created by the solana-tokens tool, so i shouldn't exists before head.
the csv file should be smth like this:
recipient_address,amount
GfvjdvM7Ue4q8D1f7FhK7Xa6PrW4Mw5VuwQxosbFvEHU,1
3C6tQpq5jZ9Pm3jgj28rPP5d3UypRkF6cd7Zy8Gw9DHz,2
8H3d4QpT4K7W8qH2wM7yL6T5dZ3E6A5sQ7vR6a2U6QzK,3

after creating the csv file catch your path to key-pair.json file by :
solana config get

and then you are good to go, run the following command to do the distribution:
solana-tokens distribute-tokens --db-path distribution.db --fee-payer /path/to/your/.config/solana/id.json --input-csv csv_file_you_created.csv --from /path/to/your/.config/solana/id.json


after that you can confirm the transaction by querying the balance of each address by using the below command:
solana balance GfvjdvM7Ue4q8D1f7FhK7Xa6PrW4Mw5VuwQxosbFvEHU


Thank you that worked but it worked for distributing SOL. Is there any way that this works for any SPL token?
@MohamadjavadSafari

yes, use solana-tokens distribute-spl-tokens command to distribute the spl tokens, one attribute is added in this command which the owner of the token and the rest of the parameters are the same.

and confirm the answer if it works so it shows up sooner for other researchers, thanks.

thanks for answering again, I did it the way it says here but now I get error from Invalid account data. Which adress or where can I find my token account adress that im supposed to write here. Thank you @Mohamad

i suggest to use the spl-token cli for the spl token related operations and use the spl-token accounts command to see a token associated token accounts of a owner, how ever you can manually calculate the associated token account of yours by using the solana cli or '@solana/web3.js` package.

perfect thank you @Mohamad
